# Python and RabbitMQ - Best way to listen to consume events from multiple channels?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have two, separate RabbitMQ instances.  I'm trying to find the best way to listen to events from both.

For example, I can consume events on one with the following:

```
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(user, pass)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host="host1", credentials=credentials))
channel = connection.channel()
result = channel.queue_declare(Exclusive=True)
self.channel.queue_bind(exchange="my-exchange", result.method.queue, routing_key='*.*.*.*.*')
channel.basic_consume(callback_func, result.method.queue, no_ack=True)
self.channel.start_consuming()
```

I have a second host, "host2", that I'd like to listen to as well.  I thought about creating two separate threads to do this, but from what I've read, pika isn't thread safe.  Is there a better way?  Or would creating two separate threads, each listening to a different Rabbit instance (host1, and host2) be sufficient?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The answer to "what is the best way" depends heavily on your usage pattern of queues and what you mean by "best". Since I can't comment on questions yet, I'll just try to suggest some possible solutions.

In each example I'm going to assume exchange is already declared.

## Threads

You can consume messages from two queues on separate hosts in single process using [`pika`](http://pika.readthedocs.org/).

You are right - as [its own FAQ states](http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html), `pika` is not thread safe, but it can be used in multi-threaded manner by creating connections to RabbitMQ hosts per thread. Making this example run in threads using [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module looks as follows:

```
import pika
import threading


class ConsumerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, host, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ConsumerThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self._host = host

    # Not necessarily a method.
    def callback_func(self, channel, method, properties, body):
        print("{} received '{}'".format(self.name, body))

    def run(self):
        credentials = pika.PlainCredentials("guest", "guest")

        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
            pika.ConnectionParameters(host=self._host,
                                      credentials=credentials))

        channel = connection.channel()

        result = channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)

        channel.queue_bind(result.method.queue,
                           exchange="my-exchange",
                           routing_key="*.*.*.*.*")

        channel.basic_consume(self.callback_func,
                              result.method.queue,
                              no_ack=True)

        channel.start_consuming()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    threads = [ConsumerThread("host1"), ConsumerThread("host2")]
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
```

I've declared `callback_func` as a method purely to use `ConsumerThread.name` while printing message body. It might as well be a function outside the `ConsumerThread` class.

## Processes

Alternatively, you can always just run one process with consumer code per queue you want to consume events.

```
import pika
import sys


def callback_func(channel, method, properties, body):
    print(body)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials("guest", "guest")

    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
        pika.ConnectionParameters(host=sys.argv[1],
                                  credentials=credentials))

    channel = connection.channel()

    result = channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)

    channel.queue_bind(result.method.queue,
                       exchange="my-exchange",
                       routing_key="*.*.*.*.*")

    channel.basic_consume(callback_func, result.method.queue, no_ack=True)

    channel.start_consuming()
```

and then run by:

```
$ python single_consume.py host1
$ python single_consume.py host2  # e.g. on another console
```

If the work you're doing on messages from queues is [CPU-heavy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound) and as long as number of cores in your CPU >= number of consumers, it is generally better to use this approach - unless your queues are empty most of the time and consumers won't utilize this CPU time*.

## Async

Another alternative is to involve some asynchronous framework (for example [`Twisted`](https://twistedmatrix.com/)) and running whole thing in single thread.

You can no longer use `BlockingConnection` in asynchronous code; fortunately, `pika` has adapter for `Twisted`:

```
from pika.adapters.twisted_connection import TwistedProtocolConnection
from pika.connection import ConnectionParameters
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor, task
from twisted.python import log


class Consumer(object):
    def on_connected(self, connection):
        d = connection.channel()
        d.addCallback(self.got_channel)
        d.addCallback(self.queue_declared)
        d.addCallback(self.queue_bound)
        d.addCallback(self.handle_deliveries)
        d.addErrback(log.err)

    def got_channel(self, channel):
        self.channel = channel

        return self.channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)

    def queue_declared(self, queue):
        self._queue_name = queue.method.queue

        self.channel.queue_bind(queue=self._queue_name,
                                exchange="my-exchange",
                                routing_key="*.*.*.*.*")

    def queue_bound(self, ignored):
        return self.channel.basic_consume(queue=self._queue_name)

    def handle_deliveries(self, queue_and_consumer_tag):
        queue, consumer_tag = queue_and_consumer_tag
        self.looping_call = task.LoopingCall(self.consume_from_queue, queue)

        return self.looping_call.start(0)

    def consume_from_queue(self, queue):
        d = queue.get()

        return d.addCallback(lambda result: self.handle_payload(*result))

    def handle_payload(self, channel, method, properties, body):
        print(body)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    consumer1 = Consumer()
    consumer2 = Consumer()

    parameters = ConnectionParameters()
    cc = protocol.ClientCreator(reactor,
                                TwistedProtocolConnection,
                                parameters)
    d1 = cc.connectTCP("host1", 5672)
    d1.addCallback(lambda protocol: protocol.ready)
    d1.addCallback(consumer1.on_connected)
    d1.addErrback(log.err)

    d2 = cc.connectTCP("host2", 5672)
    d2.addCallback(lambda protocol: protocol.ready)
    d2.addCallback(consumer2.on_connected)
    d2.addErrback(log.err)

    reactor.run()
```

This approach would be even better, the more queues you would consume from and the less CPU-bound the work performing by consumers is*.

## Python 3

Since you've mentioned `pika`, I've restricted myself to Python 2.x-based solutions, because `pika` is not yet ported.

But in case you would want to move to >=3.3, one possible option is to use [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) with one of AMQP protocol (the protocol you speak in with RabbitMQ) , e.g. [`asynqp`](https://github.com/benjamin-hodgson/asynqp) or [`aioamqp`](https://github.com/polyconseil/aioamqp).

* - please note that these are very shallow tips - in most cases choice is not that obvious; what will be the best for you depends on queues "saturation" (messages/time), what work do you do upon receiving these messages, what environment you run your consumers in etc.; there's no way to be sure other than to benchmark all implementations

Comment: Hi @Unit03 I know you have answered in 2015. I am using same twisted adapter and I am getting too many heart beats missing.You can visit my question for code and more description.                                                   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62024116/pika-twisted-adapter-is-giving-missing-too-many-heartbeat-error

Comment: Hi Vaibhav, I have responded under that question.

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example of how I use one rabbitmq instance to listen to 2 queues at the same time:

```
import pika
import threading

threads=[]
def client_info(channel):    
   channel.queue_declare(queue='proxy-python')
   print (' [*] Waiting for client messages. To exit press CTRL+C')


   def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
       print (" Received %s" % (body))

   channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='proxy-python', no_ack=True)
   channel.start_consuming()

def scenario_info(channel):    
   channel.queue_declare(queue='savi-virnet-python')
   print (' [*] Waiting for scenrio messages. To exit press CTRL+C')


   def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
      print (" Received %s" % (body))

   channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='savi-virnet-python', no_ack=True)
   channel.start_consuming()

def manager():
   connection1= pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters
  (host='localhost'))
   channel1 = connection1.channel()
  connection2= pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters
  (host='localhost'))
   channel2 = connection2.channel()
   t1 = threading.Thread(target=client_info, args=(channel1,))
   t1.daemon = True
   threads.append(t1)
   t1.start()  

   t2 = threading.Thread(target=scenario_info, args=(channel2,))
   t2.daemon = True
   threads.append(t2)


   t2.start()
   for t in threads:
     t.join()


 manager()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import asyncio
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

from aio_pika import connect_robust, Message

tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.configure("tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOLoop")
io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
asyncio.set_event_loop(io_loop.asyncio_loop)

QUEUE = asyncio.Queue()


class SubscriberHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    async def get(self):
        message = await QUEUE.get()
        self.finish(message.body)


class PublisherHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    async def post(self):
        connection = self.application.settings["amqp_connection"]
        channel = await connection.channel()
        try:
            await channel.default_exchange.publish(
                Message(body=self.request.body), routing_key="test",
            )
        finally:
            await channel.close()
            print('ok')
        self.finish("OK")

async def make_app():
    amqp_connection = await connect_robust()
    channel = await amqp_connection.channel()
    queue = await channel.declare_queue("test", auto_delete=True)
    await queue.consume(QUEUE.put, no_ack=True)
    return tornado.web.Application(
        [(r"/publish", PublisherHandler), (r"/subscribe", SubscriberHandler)],
        amqp_connection=amqp_connection,
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = io_loop.asyncio_loop.run_until_complete(make_app())
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

You can use aio-pika in async way
more examples here
https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/aio-pika/latest/aio-pika.pdf

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Pika can be used into a multithreaded consumer. The only requirement is to have a [Pika connection per thread](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html).

Pika Github repository has [an example here](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/master/examples/basic_consumer_threaded.py).

A snippet from basic_consumer_threaded.py:

```
def on_message(ch, method_frame, _header_frame, body, args):
    (conn, thrds) = args
    delivery_tag = method_frame.delivery_tag
    t = threading.Thread(target=do_work, args=(conn, ch, delivery_tag, body))
    t.start()
    thrds.append(t)

threads = []
on_message_callback = functools.partial(on_message, args=(connection, threads))
channel.basic_consume('standard', on_message_callback)
```