# Calling more than one functions as RABBITMQ message

Tags: python, function, rabbitmq, queue, pika

I am just starting to use RabbitMQ and Python in general. I have been reading the tuts on the rabbit official page, but I have no idea how to use Rabbitmq to do another things.

I have been trying to run the example of this [tutorial] (https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html), It runs well,.. BUT I need to know how can I create more than one fucntions and call them throug Rabbitmq Messages?... (I am also using this [example] ([Python and RabbitMQ - Best way to listen to consume events from multiple channels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550140/python-and-rabbitmq-best-way-to-listen-to-consume-events-from-multiple-channel)) to guide me. )

I hope someone have some idea how to do this... (I will repeat again, I am very new on this topics)...

This some code what i have.

I use this code to send the message as the tutorial..

```
import pika
import sys

url = 'amqp://oamogcgg:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@salamander.rmq.cloudamqp.com/oamogcgg'
params = pika.URLParameters(url)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
channel = connection.channel()


channel.exchange_declare(exchange='logs', exchange_type='fanout')

message = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]) or "info: THIS IS A TEST MESSAGE !!!!!!"
channel.basic_publish(exchange='logs', routing_key='', body=message)
print(" [x] Sent %r" % message)
connection.close()
```

And in this file is where I receive the message according to me.

```
import pika
import sys
import threading

threads=[]


#function 1 

def validator1(channel):    
channel.queue_declare(queue='queue_name')
print (' [*] Waiting messsaes for valiadtor1 press CTRL+C')


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
   print (" Received %s" % (body))
   sleep(2) #I need stop it for two minutes

channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='queue_name', no_ack=True)
channel.start_consuming()

#function 2

def validator2(channel):    
channel.queue_declare(queue='queue_name')
print (' [*] Waiting messsaes for valiadtor2 press CTRL+C')


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
  print (" Received %s" % (body))
  sleep(2) #I need stop it for two minutes

channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='queue_name', no_ack=True)
channel.start_consuming()



def manager():
 url = 'amqp://oamogcgg:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@salamander.rmq.cloudamqp.com/oamogcgg'
 params = pika.URLParameters(url)

#channel 1
 connection1= pika.BlockingConnection(params)
 channel1 = connection1.channel()

 channel1.exchange_declare(exchange='logs', exchange_type='fanout')
 result = channel1.queue_declare(queue='', exclusive=True)
 queue_name = result.method.queue
 channel1.queue_bind(exchange='logs', queue=queue_name)

#channel 2

 connection2= pika.BlockingConnection(params)
 channel2 = connection2.channel()


channel2.exchange_declare(exchange='logs', exchange_type='fanout')
result = channel2.queue_declare(queue='', exclusive=True)
queue_name = result.method.queue
channel2.queue_bind(exchange='logs', queue=queue_name)



#creating threads

t1 = threading.Thread(target=validator1, args=(channel1,))
t1.daemon = True
threads.append(t1)
t1.start()  

t2 = threading.Thread(target=valiadtor2, args=(channel2,))
t2.daemon = True
threads.append(t2)


t2.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()


manager()
```

Comment: What do you mean by `BUT I need to know how can I create more than one functions and call them through Rabbitmq Messages`?. Do you want to call multiple functions on the same message or do you want to call multiple consumers for the same queue?. Can you please explain your scenario a bit more clear?

Comment: Yes, I need to call mutiple fucntions on some message, is it possible?..

Answer (score 0):

If your functions are dependent(by dependent I mean, one function works on the output of the other) then, you can call all those functions one by one in your callback function. Once the last function is executed successfully you can acknowledge the message.

If those functions are independent then you can maintain multiple queues for each of the function you wanna execute on the message. The same message can be routed to multiple queues using a `fanout` exchange as mentioned in [RabbitMQ Tutorial-3](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html).

Comment: Thank you, i tried to create my functions in another file, then I only imported them in the callback function and when all of them were executed successfully I can acknowledge the message  .... I works well..... But now what I want to do is print the same acknowledge message into my producer.py file when its is received to ensure it that the message was received by the receive.py.... Do you have some idea how to do this?

Comment: You mean, you want to print the message from the producer when the consumer has positively acknowledged the message?

Comment: what I want to know is how print some message in the producer when the message received by the consumer??

or how can my producer come to know about the ack that the consumer sent when the message was received?

Comment: The producers and consumers are two different things. Producers just publish the message to the queue. Consumers consume the messages from the queue. All producers care is if the message is successfully routed to the queue. The same applies for consumers while consuming. If you want your prodcuer to know about the ack the consumer has sent, then you need to implement RPC style. That is provided in the tutorials as well https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html

Comment: Thank you, I have started to read about RPC. I think it will be the solution about what I need to implement