# RabbitMQ - Consume multiple queues

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I am working with Python, RabbitMQ and Pika.

I have multiple consumers and queues. I want one consumer to get messages from every queues. 
Let's say I have 2 consumers and 3 queues. I want each of my consumers to read messages from queue number 1, 2 and 3.

I have manage to do so with a basic_get :

basic_get(queue1)

basic_get(queue2)

basic_get(queue3)

=> Get one message from queue 1, one from queue 2, one from queue 3, then repeat.

The "problem" is that I want to use a basic_consume in order to set qos (let queues to push n messages each time). I want to get n messages from queue 1, then n messages from queue 2, n messages from queue 3 and then go back to queue 1 and so on. I don't want to consume all from queue 1, then all from the 2nd, ...

I have not find a way to implement basic_consume for multiple queues. Is it possible to implement basic_consume in my situation?

Also, do I need threads when using basic_consume? It does call a function when a message is sent in RabbitMQ. But this is a listener as I understand. So I cannot do anything while it is listening. Using threads would be helpful to process tasks while listening to new messages, right?

Thanks.

Comment: Please note it is not thread safe to share Pika connections across threads - each thread must have its own connection:  http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Consume multiple queues in python / pika](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510310/consume-multiple-queues-in-python-pika)

Answer (score 0):

set the [prefetch for the consumer](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html), and you should be able to do that.

I'm not sure about the Pika code specifically, but the example in that documentation shows it like this:

```
channel.basicQos(10); // Per consumer limit
channel.basicConsume("my-queue", false, consumer);
```

regarding threads... that depends on your specific application needs. often times, it is easier to increase the # of process instances instead of using threads. but using threads certainly is a valid way to parallelize the processing of the messages in a single process.